# How do i set the priority of mobile push notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, react-native

I am following the following documentation to set the priority of the Mobile Push channel notifications but still when viewing the logs the channel priority is -1.

Documentation I'm following to set notification priority:
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/custom-channels

part of sdk state:

```
D/~#RNMCSdkModule:"name": "com.clevertap.android.sdk.pushnotification.fcm.FcmMessageListenerService",
              "priority": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "io.invertase.firebase.messaging.ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingService",
              "priority": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.MCFirebaseMessagingService",
              "priority": -1
            },
            {
              "name": "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService",
              "priority": -500
            }
          ]
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're viewing has nothing to do with the push notification priority. Also, modifying the push notification priority is not currently supported. You should open a voice of customer request through your account executive.